# Аргумент, при котором достигается максимум функции

Tags: c++, python, математика

Требуется найти такой аргумент функции (с точностью до 10^(-6)), что при нем достигается максимум функции.

Можно предложить решение как на c++, так и на питоне (вдруг в какой-нибудь библиотеке что-нибудь есть).

Функция имеет вид

```
f(k, x_1, x_2, ...., x_n) = p(k, x_1) * p(k, x_2) * ... * p(k, x_n)
p(k, x) = indicator(x) / (k * sqrt(-x))
indicator(x) = 1, если x лежит в отрезке [-k^2, 0), иначе 0
```

x_1, x_2, ... , x_n - это константы. Переменной является только k, её значения, который достигается максимум функции и нужно найти.

Comment: Какие-нибудь свойства функции известны? В общем случае, эта задача не имеет решения.

Comment: Если функция непрерывная, если имеет один максимум на отрезке, если этот отрезок известен... Иначе есть масса неприятных частных случаев... Уточнить задачу не хотите?

Comment: @vp_arth это функция имеет вид f(k, x_1, x_2, ...., x_n) = p(k, x_1) * p(k, x_2) * ... * p(k, x_n), где функция p(k, x) = indicator(x) / (k * sqrt(-x)), где функция indicator(x) возвращает 1, если x лежит в отрезке [-k^2, 0) и возвращает 0, если иначе.

Comment: Подобные уточнения нужно добавлять в [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/651536/edit)

Comment: @vp_arth добавил.

Comment: Что-то не похоже, чтоб было решение. Смотрите сами - при x, стремящемся к 0, p(k,x) стремится к бесконечности. Отрезок со стороны нуля открыт, так что наибольшего значения просто нет...

Comment: @Harry аргументом является только k (его максимум мы ищем). x_1,..., x_n - это константы.

Comment: а ответ случайно не корень ли из максимума x? иначе индикатор 0 и всё выражение 0.

Comment: А, виноват, ошибся. Тогда, понятно, максимум надо искать от максимального по модулю x и выше (иначе будет 0). Вроде так. Но тогда -k^2 = min(x_1,..,x_n) Вроде так?

Comment: @pavel Минимума :) - исходя из знака.

Comment: Т.е., обозначая через m = min(x_1,...,x_n) имеем f_max = 1/sqrt(-x1*...*-x_n)/(-m)^(n/2). Вроде бы так...

Comment: @Алексей, а почему Вы ничего не предложили сами в качестве решения? Мне не нравится такой подход

Comment: Параметрические константы обычно обозначаются `a₁`, `a₂`, ...

Comment: если известна точная формула может аналитически взять

Answer (score 1):

Получается примерно так?

```
double x[n];
double m = x[0], M = x[0];
for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (m > x[i]) m = x[i];
    if (M < x[i]) M = x[i];
}

if (M >= 0) { /* решения нет, f(k) == 0 */ }
else { k = sqrt(-m); }
```

Comment: Почему, есть максимум не меньше нуля, то решения нет?

Comment: Все, я понял...

Comment: А как бы у нас изменился ответ, если бы в функции p(k, x) имела бы вид:
p(k, x) = indicator(x) / (k * sqrt(-x)) + e^x * const * indicator_1(x), где indicator_1 (x) = 1, если x >= 0, иначе 0.

Comment: Ну, рабочая неделя началась, теперь думайте сами :) Тут я сходу ничего хорошего придумать не могу, пожалуй, тут нужно смотреть, как ведет себя функция при конкретных значениях x, и искать максимум численно...